Questions on integer matrix multiplication
Question 1:
Given two integer matrices $A$ and $B$, and let $C$ be $AB$.
$C$ can be very big in pratice, so what is the fastest way to compute the statistical data of $C$?
For example,
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\3&4\end{pmatrix}$$
$$B=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$
The statistical data of $C$ are:



Value
Appearing times in $C$




0
2


2
1


4
1



Question 2:
Given a single value $v$, what is the fastest way to know its appearing times in $C$? Computing the product and counting the number is the only way or not?

Why would there be any faster way than just computing the product and counting the number of appearances of each integer in the result?

Say $A,B$ are $1000\times1000$ $0,1$ matrices. You want to know, say, how many $250$s there are in $AB$, faster than by computing $AB$ and counting. I'm skeptical that this can be done. Just changing a single one in $A$ to a zero can make a large change in the number of $250$s.
